# Why can't we add video (or even audio) clips to posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In [a recent question,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509540/rhoticity-in-speech) a new user asked how to classify the accent as heard  in a video clip from youtube.

However, that required going off-page to hear it, and some users objected to that.

I tried to edit to paste [the clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkIUGHnIrzw), but was informed by the system that the source format was unacceptable.

I know I have done this on other sites, such [as in this answer on Movies & TV.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/51218/is-the-title-the-walking-dead-referring-to-the-main-characters-of-the-series/51219#51219), simply by going to the [image] icon and pasting in the link.

***Why can't I do that here on EL&U?***

In general, language consists of ***spoken utterances***, less often written symbols of some sort, and Sign Language, not excluding non-verbal communication.

When we talk about English skills, it usually includes speaking, writing, reading, ***and listening.***

If we would like to fully participate in the discussion of English Language and Usage, we should be able to entertain questions about accent *based on the embedded audio*, not a transcription.

It seems that this is not the first time this question/request has been raised: there is a post on Meta going back 7 years, and [recently updated by Colleen V.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152282/embedded-audio-player-on-language-sites) Please help us by up-voting her post.

I know there may be objections even here in our own community based on "abuse", but it should not be different to handling the type of spammy images we sometimes deal with. It would just require some judicious attention to the review queue.

The benefits would out-weigh the costs in time, and just as still photos and screen shots are sometimes needed, this feature could eventually come to be seen as indispensable.

[EDIT] Serendipity, happenstance, I don't know, but [a new question popped up](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/509924/they-have-some-background-strong) in which the *off-page* link to the audio clip helped identify the dialect and flavor of the usage.

Comment: Scifi can do it too. Maybe it's only turned on on some sites?

Comment: Theres a request for embedding audio clips on language sites from '12 that I tried to revive in '16 :[Embedded audio player on language sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152282/273494). Seems hard to get anyone interested :/

Comment: If you're also referring to Colleen's link, then including that link in the FR above would direct users to that post and upvote the proposal.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It would be beneficial for ELU to have an upvoted meta post demonstrating that a good portion of the community wants the feature since it’s being added sites as needed.

Comment: I am puzzled less by the absence of this feature than this question causing such a feud. Youtube videos and audio files from various sites have been posted before asking about accents, pronunciation, etc. and no one has gone ballistic about it.

Comment: @KarlG my feud (no one else is) is aimed at the SE squad.  Having an embedded video or better still an audio clip where you could regulate the controls would be an asset to the site. Imagine if SE forbade images  for reasons of bandwidth, we could still post links to images, but it would be tiresome to leave the site every time we wanted to view an image.

Comment: I’d personally prefer not. I think the feature will result in more abuses and annoyances than in a small handful of more interesting questions. Think video transcription, “what did he say here?”, etc, more often than “this guy says he’s from NW but he appears to have a rhotic accent, how to account for this?”.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I meant the question to which your question refers.

Comment: @KarlG You would have to take a look at the "self-answer"  (since deleted) and its history.

Comment: Is this a question "Why can't we add?" which has been answered, or a feature request to add it (which **invalidates the existing answer**)?

Comment: @AndrewLeach It started out as a technical question, but evolved into a question about policy. Sorry. Yes, the answer is probably no longer valid, (and possibly flippant ie "it is what it is")  but the comments are helpful. The "Why" is now rhetorical. The "feature-request" was added by Mary-Lou, but I agreed to it.

Comment: I went ahead and put a bounty on the Meta question to try to get more attention.

Comment: I don't think additional bounty will help - I just used it to get it "featured" for a couple weeks. You have to earn rep on the main meta to post bounties there.

Comment: I think on site metas, the only thing that can be done is to ask moderators to add the "featured" tag.

Comment: Post an answer on the bounty, explaining why the FR is an asset. Crunch the numbers, EL&U has 268k users, it's the FOURTH most visited site (350k) on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)  Find a few more questions that included links to audio files and YouTube videos, and show users would benefit listening/watching these files while at the same time reading the OP.

Comment: So my bounty generated some votes, but no new answers. Not sure this feature is going to make it.

Comment: Sorry, @ColleenV...I kinda gave up on this a couple weeks ago. It just has not generated enough enthusiasm for the rest, no matter how beneficial it might seem.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is because different SE sites are differently configured with respect to whether they allow for the direct embedding of sound or video clips in posts.

Most but not all SE sites configs forbid it, including ours.

Comment: As we are a site for English, which presumably includes the spoken form, why?

Comment: @Cascabel visit MetaSe and make it a feature request. But first, be sure that the FR has not already been asked. So search like mad, there are only ten years' worth of posts, after you have sifted through 9,000 questions and think you have an original FR, work out the human hours of work it will entail developers to activate this feature. List all the cons that you can possibly imagine and then figure out to solve them. After that, you might, just might, be able to post your request and get either totally ignored by the team or downvoted and closed for being off-topic by the  community. Enjoy!

Comment: @Mari-LouA It sounds like you have had a a less than fruitful experience in a similar quest. For me it is ridiculous to exclude audio from a site that is devoted to English. It's like..I don't know; maybe designing a 4-legged animal and then saying, "whoa..gonna chop off an arm or a leg before you can participate."

Comment: No, not really. This is borne out of observation, Few FRs are received warm heartedly, those that do tend to affect positively all the sites or in particular SOverflow users, seeing as the vast majority of users on Meta are either from SO or SuperUser. EL&U doesn't count for a thing. See our requests about fonts, theme, links, and anything that would improve the appearance and functionality of EL&U.

Comment: But there's no harm in asking!

Comment: @Cascabel The feature request should be posted here on meta ELU (and not Meta SE, where it would get closed) because it only affects this site.

Comment: @laurel but it gets more eyes, and you're more likely to get a CM attention there than here. Oh, wait. The CM will likely say on EL&U "Thanks for bringing this to our attention" and then promptly disappear for the next 10 months or so.

Comment: As to my recommendation that Cascabel visit Meta and make a FR there, I really didn't know that an identical request had been posted **seven** years ago. But that wasn't closed for being off-topic was it?

Comment: Music SE can embed soundcloud I think - would that be an option for spoken words?

Comment: @Mari-LouA ["Don't give up..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjEq-r2agqc)...Kate Bush and Peter Gabriel

Comment: Have we heard a peep from a CM in seven days? From Tim Post? From any developer? And people keep telling me I'm wrong to suggest posting on MetaSE, well, this is silence is what I was talking about.  I get they're busy.